# Name for integration technique of $\int_0^\infty \log^n(x)/R(x)\,dx$ via keyhole contour.

Tags: soft-question, contour-integration

## Background

Suppose $R(x)$ is a rational function with no positive real roots, and we want to integrate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^n(x)}{R(x)} dx.$$

There's a [trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827625/121988) that I've commonly seen where the integrand is multiplied by $\log(x)$ and this is integrated over $\gamma$, the [keyhole contour](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Keyhole_contour.svg) together with the residue theorem.

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\log^{n+1}(z)}{R(z)} dz = 2\pi i\sum_{i}\operatorname{Res}_{z_i}\left(\frac{\log^{n+1}(z)}{R(z)}\right).$$

---

## Question.

Is there a name for this technique?

I see on Wikipedia that there is a related example called "[The square of the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_5_%E2%80%93_the_square_of_the_logarithm)", but I'm looking for a term that I can look up in the index of a Complex Analysis text.

Comment: I've used the methodology you described many times to evaluate this class of integrals, but I've never seen a "name" attached to it.